# Does using "most" in conversational English convey use of some statistic or data gathering?

Tags: conversation, statistics

In a conversation someone said the following:

> **Most** of the engineers working in the high-tech industry switch jobs for money.

I was a little adamant about the use of *Most* in the above statement. I was of the opinion that when one says "Most", one should have done (or read about) at least some reliable data analysis, but *Many* on the other hand better conveys the meaning (that this is an *opinion*) in this context. But I couldn't back up my argument correctly.

Should people use *most* only when some statistical analysis can back it up (and the percentage of favorable cases is more than say 80%) and in the cases where it is an anecdotal evidence, resort to using *many*?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. Your point is that the claim might be wrong? That's not a question about language; it's an epistemological question. If she said "Many of the engineers..." that also might be wrong. No? And "My boss is a Capricorn" might be wrong.

Comment: Perhaps this might also be an "ettiquette" question. From a language perspective, context, and the tone of the sentences around it should clue in the listener whether a person is sharing opinions off the cuff or if they have some particular knowledge. If they've already been talking about "what they've heard", I don't think a conversation requires every subsequent sentence to be qualified. There are different expectations when someone is speaking from a stage as an authority or writing about a subject than in a conversation.

Comment: @Chaim, my _opinion_ is that _many_ is to be preferred to _most_ in the cases involving anecdotal evidence and my observation is that _many_ people use _most_ rather loosely. The reason I think _many_ is appropriate is that its estimation involves an _absolute_ number, whereas (I thought that) estimation of _most_ involves a relative (e.g. some percentage) number. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I agree that if anecdotal evidence does not justify the belief that most engineers switch jobs for money, we should not claim that most do. And if the evidence does not justify the belief that many do, we should not make that unjustified claim either. But the reason to avoid unjustified claims has to do with honesty, not with any ambiguity in the unjustified claims.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Nope.

Longer answer: **Most** only means "*the majority of*".  It implies more than half, although in common usage, I think it is often nearly all, but that isn't what the dictionary says:

> ***[Most](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/most)***
>
> PRONOUN & DETERMINER
>
> 1 superlative of many, much
>
> 2 Greatest in amount or degree.
>
> *[as determiner]* ‘they've had the most success’
>
> *[as pronoun]* ‘they had the most to lose’
>
> 2.1 The majority of; nearly all of.
>
> *[as determiner]* ‘most oranges are sweeter than these’
>
> *[as pronoun]* ‘I spent most of the winter on the coast’

A quick trip around the internet will provide a plethora of examples of people making claims using *most* and other superlatives without or even contrary to any evidence.

**Edit:** *Many* simply means *a large number of* -- more than a few, but not all.

> ***[Many](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/many)***
>
> ADJECTIVE, PRONOUN, & DETERMINER
>
> A large number of.
>
> *[as determiner]* ‘many people agreed with her’
>
> *[as pronoun]* ‘the solution to many of our problems’

I hope this helps!

Comment: Right, since many merely means _large number of_, isn't that more appropriate (in this context)?

Comment: Not necessarily.  _Most_ and _many_ only refer to quantity; they make not guarantee of veracity.  If I were to say _Most blue whales speak Portuguese_ it carries no more or less implication of accuracy than would _Many blue whales speak Portuguese_.  The only difference between the two is the *number* of blue whales that purportedly speak Portuguese.  (In fact, both are false, of course, as we all know blue whales speak Bengali.)

Comment: As to your question _Should people use most only when some statistical analysis can back it up_ -- well, I would say yes, but this is the internet and that ain't gonna happen.  8^)

Comment: Your original example, _Most of the engineers working in the high-tech industry switch jobs for money._ is making the claim that nearly all -- the vast majority -- of engineers switch jobs just for the money and not for other reasons.  I don't know that I would agree with that without supporting evidence, but, on the other hand, I have no evidence to refute it.  (Other than that the last time I switched jobs it definitely *wasn't* for money -- and if I were to get a new job now, money would only be one part of my decision.)

Comment: I agree that I think of "most" as less that most(used my way) people think of "most" today. Many people fly into a tizzy when you say "most" if they know a few people who don't agree.  And never say something like most people are heterosexual even if that's a full 90% plus of the people, although you would certainly get away with saying most (or even the vast majority?) of people are right handed. MY POINT is that there is also a political/emotional/contextual influence on where thresholds are set.